# Java ThreadFactory with Queue

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, threadpool

I am trying to write and read from ArrayBlockingQueue via threads. I have thread factory and worker threads but for some reason I cannot read the data that I pass to to worker threads, within the worker threads. Any idea? Thanks.

```
public class CommunicationThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {

  @Override
  public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable){
     Thread thread=new Thread(runnable);
     return thread;
  }
}

public class ThreadEx implements Runnable {

private byte[] pack;

private final BlockingQueue writeBlockingQueue;

public Writer(BlockingQueue writeBlockingQueue, byte[] pack) {
    this.writeBlockingQueue = writeBlockingQueue;
    this.pack = pack;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);//Even this line block it wont process below this line. Even after time out. 
    writeBlockingQueue.put(pack);//Tried even with disabling put and takes from queue. still did not work
    System.out.println("In Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() +" got "+ this.pack.length);// This line does not even produce output. 
    writeBlockingQueue.take();
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

ExecutorService connectionThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15,new 
CommunicationThreadFactory());
    BlockingQueue<byte[]> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10, true);

    byte[] packet = new byte[]{0x63, 0x41, 0x35, 0x19}; 
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       connectionThreadPool.execute(new ThreadEx());
  }
}
```

Comment: _"I cannot read the data"_ -- What is stopping you? You have not explained the problem.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site.

Comment: "System.out.println("In Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() +" got "+ this.pack.length);// This line does not even produce output."   This simply does not even print out anything on the console. No output as I stated before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not compile. After correcting some synax errors, it works fine.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class CommunicationThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        return thread;
    }
}

public class ThreadEx implements Runnable {

    private byte[] pack;

    private final BlockingQueue writeBlockingQueue;

    public ThreadEx(BlockingQueue writeBlockingQueue, byte[] pack) {
        this.writeBlockingQueue = writeBlockingQueue;
        this.pack = pack;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            writeBlockingQueue.put(pack);
            // This line does not even produce output.
            System.out.println("In Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " got "
                + this.pack.length);
            writeBlockingQueue.take();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        ExecutorService connectionThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15, new
                CommunicationThreadFactory());
        BlockingQueue<byte[]> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10, true);

        byte[] packet = new byte[]{0x63, 0x41, 0x35, 0x19};
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            connectionThreadPool.execute(new ThreadEx(blockingQueue, packet));
        }
    }
}
```